# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity: NumberFormatException: For input string: "--"

Tags: java, android, время

Мое приложение предназначено в основном для молитв. Рассчитывает время молитвы на основе долготы и широты. Но приложение не может рассчитать время молитвы фаджр и иша в городах больше 52,8 Longtidue. Например, до Тамбова считается, а в Москве не учитывается время молитв.

**Скриншот:**

[image: Скриншот]

**1) `MainActivity.java`:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*      Initialization Methods      */
        _LocationSET.checkCurrentLocation(this);
        _AlarmSET.setPowerConceptions(this);
        _AlarmSET.setAlarmPermissions(this);
        _TimesSET.updateTimes(this);
        _DisplaySET.setLanguagePreferences(this);
        reloadMainActivityOnResume = false;
        /*              ********            */

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        upComingTimePoint = _TimesSET.comingTimePointIndex();
        if(_TimesSET.isItGoogleCalendar(this)) initializeDateViewsWithGoogleApi();
        else initializeDateViews();
        initializeTimePoints();
        initializeTheme();
        startTimer();
        AlarmsScheduler.fire(this,Calendar.getInstance()); //set Alarms

...
```

**2) `_TimesSet.java`:**

```
  public class _TimesSET {
    ...

        public static String[] times = {"04:27","05:51","11:19","14:23","16:46","18:05"};

    ...

    public static long getPrayerTimeMillis(int i,boolean upComing) {
       Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
       long nowMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
       cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(times[i].substring(0, 2)));
       cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(times[i].substring(3, 5)));
       cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        if(nowMillis > cal.getTimeInMillis() && upComing) cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);// For upcoming Fajr after Isha
       return cal.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    ...

    public static int comingTimePointIndex(){
        int i = 0;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() > getPrayerTimeMillis(i,false)) if(++i == 6) break;
        return i<6?i:0;
    }

    ...
```

**3) Ошибка:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron/bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron.Activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "--"
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "--"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron.Times._TimesSET.getPrayerTimeMillis(_TimesSET.java:178)
        at bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron.Times._TimesSET.comingTimePointIndex(_TimesSET.java:155)
        at bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:172)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
2021-05-15 21:42:43.012 15449-15449/bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron/bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron.Activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "--"
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "--"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron.Times._TimesSET.getPrayerTimeMillis(_TimesSET.java:178)
        at bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron.Times._TimesSET.comingTimePointIndex(_TimesSET.java:155)
        at bilibqoy.mohirjonnnikibuilova.namozvsquron.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:172)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

**4) Ссылки:**

[Мой Код Github](https://github.com/MsdSdm/Code.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эту ошибку

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "--"

нужно исправить заменой кода

```
public static final String[] times = {"04:27","05:51","11:19","14:23","16:46","18:05"};
...
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(_TimesSet.times[i].substring(0, 2)));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(_TimesSet.times[i].substring(3, 5)));
```